# CreateInsert not working

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I want to get `RowId` of newly created row from a backing bean.Below is my code that i am executing from a backing bean.

```
Util.callOperation(bindings, "CreateInsert", null);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    RichTable r = getOvertimeTable();

    for (Object selectedRowKey : r.getSelectedRowKeys()) {

        String rowId = r.getClientRowKeyManager().getClientRowKey(context, r, selectedRowKey);
        //System.out.println(rowId);

    }
```

When i execute above code , no new row is created i.e. `af:table` shows no new rows even though i am executing `CreateInsert`. If i comment 
`String rowId = r.getClientRowKeyManager().getClientRowKey(context, r, selectedRowKey);`
`CreateInsert` works i.e. `af:table` shows newly created row.
I have set partial trigger of `af:table` also.

EDIT: If i remove the sequence from primary key, my createinsert works.

What do i have to do to get the ID of newly created row?

Answer (score 0):

The rowId cannot be known before the commit. So
it is better to use the DB sequence as primary key in you Entity Object

Comment: but i am able to get the rowid, the only thing happeing is CreateInsert doesn't works. If i remove sequence from primary key then createInsert Works.